# Using Tableau Filters with Maps - Always Include a Value, but Exclude it from Filter

Tags: tableau-api

I've built a geographic report for a new system that has very little data in it so far.  The report combines two maps into one image with dual axis.

The first map shows different regions identified by color.  It's supposed to always be visible, no matter what values are selected in a filter.

The second map shows business-related data, e.g., geographical locations of offices and number of applicants per office.

The data set is a union of business-related data and geographic data containing nulls in business-related columns.

The problem is that the nulls are showing in the filters, and this is confusing for the users.  Basically, the nulls always need to be selected in order for the general map to be visible.  If a user deselects NULL from any of the filters, the map disappears.

How can I fix it?  Ideally, the NULLs (or a value replacing the null) should always be included in the data and be always excluded from the filter.

Comment: Share your code, I don't think anybody can help you this way.

Comment: Arash, thank you for responding.  I've made [a very simple sample file to demonstrate the issue](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoubkNx6NrfriluuG_RVKHqxq3ty).

Comment: The file contains an extract, a map, and a filter called Office.  The filter shows two options, including NULL.  If you deselect NULL in the filter, the map disappears.